# algorithm for searching in ranges

Tags: algorithm, search, range, array-algorithms

I am given a huge list of objects with attributes x and y. We are required to search for all objects lying between a given upper and lower bound of both the attributes.

I was wondering if there is an efficient algorithm to implement this.

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding "required": note that if this is a homework question, please tag it as `homework`, thank you!

Comment: Hi, it is just one of my personal projects, and not a homework. So, I think I will leave it as it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quadtree or a spatial index (a space-filling curve, for example a hilbert curve).

Answer (score 2):

There are standard algorithms for this.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree for one.